# How to refer to view controller in a class that the view controller imports?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have two classes in my app, `GHHaiku` (a subclass of `NSObject`) and `GHViewController`, which imports `GHHaiku`.  In `GHViewController` I've instantiated `GHHaiku` like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) GHHaiku *ghhaiku;
```

So when I need to call a method from `GHHaiku` in `GHViewController`, I can do `[self.ghhaiku callThisMethod];`

However, I can't figure out what to do if `GHHaiku` needs information from `GHViewController`.  There's a `UISegmentedControl`in `GHViewController`, for example, and there's a method in `GHHaiku` that needs to know which segment of the `UISegmentedControl` has been chosen.  How do I get it this information?  I suppose I could create an `int` property in `GHHaiku` and then, in `GHViewController`, assign the value of the `UISegmentedControl` to that property, but that seems cumbersome and I can't imagine there's not a more elegant way to do it.

So what should I do?

(I suspect that [Refer to a main view controller property by another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189236/refer-to-a-main-view-controller-property-by-another-class) might answer my question but I'm not quite advanced enough to understand the answer given.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an architectural issue that could benefit from think about [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and more clearly breaking things down roughly along MVC (model/view/controller) lines.  See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) on MVC competency in Cocoa.

Is `GHHaiku` a model object?  If so, then it shouldn't really 'know' about things going on in the view layer.

Comment: Oh, my God, that should have been obvious!  I've been so concerned with the little details that I forgot all about MVC....  Thank you!

Comment: No worries.  A lot my own conundra can be traced back to incompletely thinking through those architectural issues at an early enough stage.